# Charts indexable or enumerable C#

Tags: charts

I put 8 charts in my form . I want to set some parameters of the charts in a loop , not one by one . Charts don't belong to Controls  .  Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add all your Chart objects to a Collection i.e. to a `List<Chart>` and iterate over them to modify all their properties like this:

do this in your form constructor

```
List<Chart> _charts = new List<Chart>();
_charts.Add(chart1);
_charts.Add(chart2);
```

Call this method when you want to change all background colors to black.

```
void changeChartsBackground()
{
    foreach(var chart in _charts)
    {
         chart.Background = Color.Black;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which .Net version do you use? Do you use this [Chart class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Thank you for response . I'm using VS2010 C#  and NET4.0 .                    
When I pasted the code , " Chart " as type - was'nt recognised.                  
Then I've changed it into ''Control''  and it ran .

Answer (score 0):

*Finally it looks like this:*

```
List<Control> _charts = new List<Control>();
_charts.Add(chart1); 
_charts.Add(chart2);

foreach (Control _chart in _charts)
{
_chart.BackColor = Color.Blue;
}
```